# mvvmcross databinding help required

Tags: data-binding, uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Trying to learn about mvvmcross and xib editor - I have followed example code from

http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html

and incorporated some within my code.

```
 namespace ConX.UI.Touch.Cells
 { 
 [Register("JobCell")]
    public partial class JobCell : MvxBaseBindableTableViewCell
    {
    public static NSString Identifier = new NSString("JobCell");
    public const string BindingText = @"{'JobDescription':{'Path':'Description'}, 'JobScheduledForDate':{'Path':'ScheduledForDate'}, 'JobNumber':{'Path':'JobNo'}}";


    public JobCell(): base(BindingText)
    {
    }

    public JobCell(IntPtr handle): base(BindingText, handle)
    {
    }       

    public JobCell (string bindingText): base(bindingText, UITableViewCellStyle.Default, Identifier)
    {
    }

    public string JobDescription 

    {
        get { return this.DescriptionLabel.Text; }
        set { this.DescriptionLabel.Text = value; }
    }


    public string JobScheduledForDate
    {
        get { return ScheduledForDateLabel.Text; }
        set { ScheduledForDateLabel.Text = value; }
    }


    public string JobNumber
    {
        get { return NumberLabel.Text; }
        set { NumberLabel.Text = value; }
    }

}
```

}

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace ConX.UI.Touch.Cells
{
partial class JobCell
{
    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel DescriptionLabel { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel ScheduledForDateLabel { get; set; }

    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel NumberLabel { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (DescriptionLabel != null) {
            DescriptionLabel.Dispose ();
            DescriptionLabel = null;
        }

        if (ScheduledForDateLabel != null) {
            ScheduledForDateLabel.Dispose ();
            ScheduledForDateLabel = null;
        }

        if (NumberLabel != null) {
            NumberLabel.Dispose ();
            NumberLabel = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I just cannot get this work with the following error thrown - seems outlets are not being created?

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at ConX.UI.Touch.Cells.JobCell.set_JobDescription (System.String value) [0x00008] in
/Volumes/ConXPrototype/Conx.UI.Touch/Cells/JobCell.cs:32
at    
       ConX.UI.Touch.Views.BaseJobListView`2+TableSource[ConX.Core.ViewModels.JobListViewModel,Syst
em.DateTime].GetOrCreateCellFor (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView,
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath, System.Object item) [0x00025] in  
/Volumes/ConXPrototype/Conx.UI.Touch/Views/BaseJobListView.cs:101
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Views.MvxBaseBindableTableViewSource.GetCell  
(MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) 
[0x00000] in <filenam
```

[image: exception]

Many thanks
Kern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are running an older version of the MvvmCross framework binaries.

There were some key changes we made in the last 4 weeks which delay data-binding from occurring until the cell and source are really available for binding. You can see these changes at [Bindable Cell changes on GitHub](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commits/26d355bae65c7eeb9f112ecde8fa1b0045c792a9/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxBaseBindableTableViewCell.cs%20BindableTableViewCell%20changes%20on%20GitHub)

There are two possible fixes:

**A.** Upgrade to more recent assemblies - the ones used when recording that blog post are in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Lib/MvvmCross (or there are binaries released currently on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/p/mvvmcross-binaries_7.html)

**B.** *OR* keep on the older assemblies, but you need to protect your get/set methods by testing for null controls like:

```
public string JobNumber
{
    get { return NumberLabel == null ? null : NumberLabel.Text; }
    set { if (NumberLabel == null) return; NumberLabel.Text = value; }
}
```

Sorry about this change in the libraries - MvvmCross does continue to improve, the sample/blog posts do not always catch up and this can cause confusion in the samples.

---

If you choose to update to the latest assemblies, then Swiss Binding syntax will also become available, allowing you to switch from:

```
public const string BindingText = @"{
   'JobDescription':{'Path':'Description'}, 
   'JobScheduledForDate':{'Path':'ScheduledForDate'}, 
   'JobNumber':{'Path':'JobNo'}}";
```

to

```
public const string BindingText = @"
   JobDescription Description; 
   JobScheduledForDate ScheduledForDate; 
   JobNumber JobNo";
```

but this is only an option - you can stick with JSON if you prefer.

For more on Swiss Binding, see http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/01/awesome-mvvmcross-swiss-bindings-for.html

Comment: Updated binaries, switched to RegisterNibForCellReuse() and away laughing. 
Thanks Stuart - awesome framework.